# .trx test file generation in ng run test for sonar cloud code coverage

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, sonarcloud

I am facing issues to get code coverage report via sonar cloud in my angular project.

I have configured karma tool to get the test report. Output file is generating test report in .xml format. I configured the test report path in sonar as well:

```
sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/TestResults/*.xml
```

But sonar cloud is searching for .trx extension test report.Below is the error log.

```
06:16:44.724  Looking for TRX files in: D:\a\1\TestResults
06:16:44.724  No test results files found
06:16:45.083  Did not find any binary coverage files in the expected location.
06:16:45.083  Falling back on locating coverage files in the agent temp directory.
06:16:45.083  Searching for coverage files in D:\a\_temp
```

Requesting to help me to resolve the same.

Comment: Does your issue solved now? Does the test result file could be found successfully now? Feel free to let us know the latest status.

Answer (score 1):

By default, if you not specified other file path, the TRX file is exist under `s` file, it's file path is under 
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory), not $(Agent.BuildDirectory).

[image]

According to the error message:

> Looking for TRX files in: D:\a\1\TestResults

`D:\a\1\TestResults`, this is the incorrect file path which is the TRX file exist by default.

So, if you did not specified another file path in VSTest, the `.TRX` file path should be reading as `D:\a\1\s\TestResults` which is under `$(build.SourcesDirectory)` instead of $(Agent.BuildDirectory) .

Answer (score 0):

You can add a copy tasks like this to transfer what is generated on test to what is the path Sonarqube is looking.

[image]